# c# Set an port number (integer value) if a specific key is entered? c#

Tags: c#, string, set

I am trying to be able to store an integer if a certain key is found in the text.

the key can be anywhere in the string, For example:

```
-p 40 Bond "James bond"
```

or

```
bond "james bond" -p 40
```

or

```
bond -p 40 "james bond"
```

So int port = 40.

This is my attempt but it's quite broken as port returns as 0.

```
if (mystring.Contains("-p"))
    {
        string sport = "";
        string[] splits = mystring.Split(' ');
        for (int i = 0; i < splits.Length; i++)
        {
            if (splits[i].Contains(" "))
                sport = splits[i].Trim();
        }

        int.TryParse(sport, out port);

        Console.WriteLine(port);
        return;
    }
```

The port number comes immediatly after -p. Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
string[] splits = mystring.Split(' ');
for (int i = 0; i < splits.Length; i++)
{
    if (splits[i] == "-p")
    {
        sport = int.Parse(splits[i+1]);
    }
}
```

Once you detect `-p` you want to parse the *next* entry as your port value.

Comment: I'd change the loop condition to `i < splits.Length - 1` to avoid exception in case nothing is passed after `-p`

Comment: @digEmAll: In that case I'd argue this is an invalid command line and possible *should* throw an exception

Comment: This works perfectly. I really appreciate your answer (I cant select answer for another few minuites).

Why did i not think of this??

Comment: This method will fail if the string argument contains `-p`as a part of the key. For example, `mystring = "bond -p 40 \"james -p 300 bond\""`. Also, this method counts the last occurrence of `-p`.

Comment: @BrokenGlass: correct, but it should not throw a generic and poorly informative IndexOutOfRange exception. The OP should probably handle the case properly :)

Comment: I think for what I am doing, this is fine. And yes, I will handle exceptions, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use regulare expression such as

```
        string pattern = @"-p (\d+)";
        string input = "sdf -p 400 sdfa";

        var matched = Regex.Match(input, pattern);
        var port = matched.Groups[1].Value;
```

port will give 400